# Crear Stored Procedure que llene una tabla

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedure, wcf, sql-server-2005

Tengo una aplicación móvil que llama a distintos servicios que tengo en `c#` con `Wcf`. El asunto es que tengo uno de esos servicios en que el usuario desde el móvil envía un objeto llamado `Medicion`. Este objeto tiene una lista de `CeldaKeyValUpload`.

```
public class Medicion
{
    [DataMember]
    public string medicion_user_email { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string medicion_user_nombre { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string medicion_app_os { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string medicion_app_version { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string medicion_latitud { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string medicion_longitud { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string medicion_sala_id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string medicion_codigo_empresa { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string medicion_codigo_cadena { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string medicion_codigo_modulo { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string medicion_categoria_codigo { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<CeldaKeyValUpload> celdas { get; set; }
}
```

Y

```
public class CeldaKeyValUpload
{
    [DataMember]
    public int celda_id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string celda_key_codigo { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string celda_key_valor { get; set; }
}
```

La lista que me puede llegar desde el móvil puede ser muy extensa, digamos un ejemplo 200 registros. En mi base de datos tengo dos tablas una llamada `MedicionEncabezado` y `MedicionDetalle`. En la primera tabla se guarda todo lo de la clase `Medicion` excepto la lista `CeldaKeyValUpload`, ya que esta se guarda en `MedicionDetalle`.

El problema que tengo es que me pongo en el caso que por cualquier motivo el móvil pierda internet y no pueda subir estos 200 registros. Para esto he creado tablas temporales llamadas `TmpMedicionEncabezado` y `TmpMedicionDetalle`. Cuando el dispositivo envía los datos, carga estas tablas temporales, ***y una vez que termine exitosamente, la carga llena mis tablas oficiales con los datos***. Es por esto que necesito crear un `Stored Procedure` que se encargue de pasar los datos de las tablas temporales a las tablas oficiales. **¿Por qué hago esto?** Para no llenar mi tabla de datos basura.

El problema que tengo es que no sé cómo obtener los datos de las tablas temporales y guardarlos en las tablas oficiales. Aún no me manejo mucho en `sql-server-2005`.

Comment: No hay necesidad de usar tablas temporales.  Si quieres evitar crear datos basura, para eso puedes usar transacciones.

Comment: Transacciones... no habia oido de eso pero voy a investigar si es que me sirve! Gracias @sstan

Comment: Ahora que leo otra vez la pregunta, no entiendo el problema de la interrupción de Internet. Como el móvil no comunica directamente con la base de datos, no veo como pueda crear basura, a menos que suceda un error en tu servicio, pero no porque el Internet se interumpió.

Comment: Se que es un poco exagerado, pero estoy pensando en el error del lado del servidor, algun dato mal enviado, caida del servidor y cualquier problema que pueda causarse, la app que estoy trabajando es para un cliente importante y es riguroso la revision entonces estoy trabajando en algo bien riguroso

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En vez de tablas temporales, usa una transacción.

El uso de una transacción te permite efectuar varios cambios a los datos en tus tablas por medio de varias sentencias SQL, pero los cambios se aplican a la base de datos de forma atómica. En otras palabras, o todos los cambios son aplicados a tu base de datos, o ninguno es aplicado. Pero no es posible que solo una parte de los cambios sean aplicados, lo que pudiera causar corrupción de los datos. En efecto, el uso de una transacción permite efectuar varias operaciones como si se hubieran efectuado de un solo.

Para que tus cambios formen parte de una transacción, debes ejecutar [`SqlConnection.BeginTransaction()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/86773566(v=vs.110).aspx) para indicar donde comienzan las operaciones que forman parte de la transacción, y [`SqlTransaction.Commit()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction.commit(v=vs.110).aspx) o [`SqlTransaction.Rollback()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction.rollback(v=vs.110).aspx) para indicar donde termina. `Commit` confirma que quieres que todos los cambios se apliquen de un solo a la base de datos, y `Rollback` indica que quieres descartar todos los cambios que hayas efectuado desde que comenzó la transacción.

Aquí te dejo un modelo de cómo puedes usar una transacción para evitar corrupción de tus datos en caso de error. Prueba agregando un error artificial que ocurre en medio de la transacción y verás que no vas a encontrar datos basura parciales en tu base de datos.

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("..."))
{
    conn.Open();

    // transacción empieza aquí.
    using (var tx = conn.BeginTransaction())
    {
        bool exito = false;

        try
        {
            // digamos que tienes que insertar varias entidades
            // uno por uno en un ciclo por medio de un stored procedure.
            foreach (var entidad in listaDeEntidades)
            {
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(
                    "insertarEntidad",
                    conn,
                    tx))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@param1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = entidad.Propiedad;
                    // ...
                    // otros parámetros
                    // ...

                    // Aquí, el cambio se manda a la base de datos,
                    // pero queda en "stand by", por decirlo así,
                    // hasta que hagas el "commit" final más abajo
                    // después de completar todos los cambios.
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }

            // Si alcanzamos este punto, quiere decir que no hubo ningún error
            // y que podemos hacer el commit (confirmacón final).
            // De lo contrario, hay que hacer un Rollback.
            exito = true;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (exito)
            {
                // Confirma todos los cambios hechos dentro de la transacción.
                // Es como si hubiéramos hecho todos los cambios de un solo.
                tx.Commit();
            }
            else
            {
                // Si exito == false, significa que surgió un error
                // durante la transacción. Rollback descarta todos los cambios
                // hechos durante la transacción hasta este punto.
                tx.Rollback();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: gracias! me sirvio y solucione mi problema sin hacer las tablas temporales... Saludos

Answer (score 3):

No sé cómo envías los datos, pero si los envías todos juntos y de una sola llamada al servicio web, este no debe hacer nada hasta que no se complete la subida, es decir si se corta la conexión, no debería desencadenarse el método del web service. Pon un punto de interrupción, haz la prueba y nos cuentas.
Espero que sea de ayuda. Saludos!

Comment: Quizas no me exprese bien en la pregunta, pero todas las validaciones y posibles errores van a ser del lado del servidor, por eso quiero encontrar la mejor manera de realizarlo