# Varias operaciones a base de datos que se comporten como una sola

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Estoy haciendo un sistema en el que, en ocasiones, debo realizar 3 o más movimientos en la base de datos: leer un campo, insertar en otra tabla, y actualizar algunas tablas; la situación aquí es que, en ocasiones, la inserción o la actualización no se realizan debido a algún error inesperado, en esos casos requiero que todas las operaciones realizadas hasta el error, se deshagan. ¿Hay forma de hacerle saber a C# o a SQL que debe deshacerlas?

Por poner un ejemplo, al capturar la factura de un proveedor, se realizan las siguientes operaciones:

1. Se lee, de una tabla, el consecutivo para la inserción en CxP (cuentas por pagar)
2. Se incrementa el consecutivo mencionado en el punto anterior
3. Se escribe en la tabla de CxP los datos del documento
4. Se modifica la existencia en la tabla de productos
5. Se agrega registro en la tabla de Kardex

Lo que quiero saber es si hay alguna forma de, si llegara haber algún error, por ejemplo en el punto 4, que hiciera un "rollback" todos los puntos anteriores.

Muchas gracias por su atención y su tiempo.

Comment: Las diferentes operaciones, ¿las harías todas dentro de un stored procedure, o serian diferentes operaciones lanzadas desde tu código c#?

Comment: Tal vez esto te ayude: http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/32887/18951.

Comment: No soy bueno con procedimientos almacenados :-(  Así que lo hago con consultas lanzadas desde C#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como dice Flxtr o bien tambien podes hacerlo desde C# con SqlTransaction.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    // Start a local transaction.
    SqlTransaction sqlTran = connection.BeginTransaction();

    // Enlist a command in the current transaction.
    SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.Transaction = sqlTran;

    try
    {
        // Execute two separate commands.
        command.CommandText =
          "INSERT INTO Production.ScrapReason(Name) VALUES('Wrong size')";
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        command.CommandText =
          "INSERT INTO Production.ScrapReason(Name) VALUES('Wrong color')";
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        // Commit the transaction.
        sqlTran.Commit();
        Console.WriteLine("Both records were written to database.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle the exception if the transaction fails to commit.
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

        try
        {
            // Attempt to roll back the transaction.
            sqlTran.Rollback();
        }
        catch (Exception exRollback)
        {
            // Throws an InvalidOperationException if the connection 
            // is closed or the transaction has already been rolled 
            // back on the server.
            Console.WriteLine(exRollback.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Lo mismo seria si quisieras reemplazar los queries embebidos por stored procedures, solo tendrias que crear un command por cada uno de ellos sobre la misma conexion.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/2k2hy99x(v=vs.110).aspx

Saludos

Answer (score 3):

Es posible manejando una transacción en conjunto con un `TRY` `CATCH` además de mostrar el mensaje de la excepción que se generó, por ejemplo:

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    -- Aquí van todas las operaciones en base de datos que desees realizar:

    SELECT Id
    FROM Tabla

    UPDATE Tabla2
    SET Valor = 'ValorNuevo'

    DELETE
    FROM Tabla3
    WHERE Id = IdRecuperado

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

    SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE()
END CATCH
```