# Como puedo realizar 3 consultas en una sola sentencia? MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Quiero realizar tres consultas en una sola misma linea, seria insert, select y delete, insert en la nueva tabla, select de la tabla de donde vienen los datos y delete para eliminarlos, pero mis conocimientos no llegan hasta alli xD, aqui les dejo la consulta para que tenga una idea.

```
INSERT INTO `finished_products` 
        (room, name, lot, quantity_packed, pallet) SELECT room, name, lot, quantity_to_packed, finished_pallets 
        FROM `current_products` WHERE `room`=:room"
```

una vez terminado eso quiero que ejecute DELETE * FROM `current_products` WHERE `room`=:room, lo puedo hacer pero seria con una consulta aparte, quisiera saber si hay manera de juntarla, lei algo sobre la consulta MERGE, pero este no sale en la version de mi mysql, gracias :)

Comment: Hola @plus! Revisa si te sirve [este tema](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/53022/varias-operaciones-a-base-de-datos-que-se-comporten-como-una-sola). Es una pregunta que hice hace tiempo, y estoy seguro que MySQL también debe tener transacciones.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que no hagas las tres consultas en una, en primera instancia me parece que no se puede desde PHP a no ser que las separes o bien que lo hagas con un `trigger` desde tu BD, ademas de eso es mala practica hacer todo en una sola linea ya que queda ilegible a largo plazo y se vuelve poco optimo para escalabilidad.

Ahora tu consulta este semanticamente bien, si corre entonces lo que puedes hacer es lo siguiente

```
INSERT INTO `finished_products` 
    (room, name, lot, quantity_packed, pallet) SELECT room, name, lot, quantity_to_packed, finished_pallets 
    FROM `current_products` WHERE `room`=:room"
DELETE FROM room WHERE room = :room
```

De esta manera tienes mas control, la otra manera seria por trigger, la logica quedaria si un elemento es insertado a `finished_products` en el evento `after insert` puedes leer de eso [aqui](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/mysql-after-insert-trigger/) entonces se eliminar el elemento de la tabla `room`

Answer (score 0):

se puede desde el backend con php o cualquier de backend que gustes, pero si quiero hacerlo en el SQL existen funcionas propias de SQL llamadas triggers te permite tener algo parecido a funciones dentro de la base de datos, las cuales se ejecutan bajo ciertas condiciones , https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/2008/07/11/triggersql/ aqui lo explican un poco mejor